# How do I install AMD R9 380 drivers on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: amd-graphics

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 17.10 just to try out new things, I was wondering how do I install the lastest drivers for my GPU?

I have been playing with Ubuntu before but not with a Desktop version only CLI.

Comment: Here you go: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

Comment: Drivers for the R9 380 are already included in Ubuntu by default. You don't need to install anything else.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thank you! Does it come with a software similar to the one on Windows where I can change saturation and such?

Comment: I don't know. :~)